# 0 appearing on a c++ code after input , and array doesnt working

Tags: c++, arrays, string

so i make a program to count how many vowels (a, e, i , o u) in the sentence.

if i input :

- 2
- hello
- world

iw will output :

- 0
- 0
- 2
- 3

the output i want :

- 2
- 1
- // because hello have 2 vowels and world have 1 vowels.

i have tried a lot of way to do it but is still error

this is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string stringsoal2 ;
int repeat, x, sum = 1, jumlahvokal = 0, jumlahvokalarr, memory_vokal[100];


int main(){
    cin >> repeat;
        for (int z = 0; z <= repeat; z++) {
            getline(cin, stringsoal2);
            for (int i = 0; i < stringsoal2.length(); i++) {
                if ((stringsoal2[i] == ('a')) || (stringsoal2[i] == ('i')) || (stringsoal2[i] == ('u')) || (stringsoal2[i] == ('e')) || (stringsoal2[i] == ('o'))) {
                    jumlahvokal++;
                    
                }
                
            }
            memory_vokal[sum] = jumlahvokal;
            sum++;

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
            cout << memory_vokal[i] << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: why 3 user inputs should result in only 2 outputs?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You need to reset `jumlahvokal` for each word.

Comment: Also, with `sum = 1` you will be off by one. Use `sum = 0`. Or just use `repeat` instead of `sum`.

Comment: `for (int z = 0; z <= repeat; z++)` how many times does this loop execute?

Comment: In addition to what has been said above, it’s easy to spot that (1) you don’t zero the `jumlahvokal` in every cycle, which is why your counts keep accumulating (3 = 1 + 2 etc.), and (2) you start writing into `memory_vokal` from index `1`, but then print it starting from index `0`, which you never set. `valgrind` would have told you that. Always use `valgrind`.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution of your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void solve()
{
    vector<char> vowels={'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    vector<string> words={"hello", "world"};
    for(int i=0; i<words.size(); ++i)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0; j<words[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            for(char vowel : vowels)
            {
                if(vowel==words[i][j])
                {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<"word <- "<<words[i]<<", count <- "<<count<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
word <- hello, count <- 2
word <- world, count <- 1
```

Comment: `std::unordered_set<char>` would fit this situation way better than a `std::vector<char>`.